# AppInventor: Fusion Tables SQL query UPDATE

Tags: sql, api, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I'm using fusion tables with an android app that I'm developing in AppInventor, and I had a question about the SQL Query for updating a row.

Now, before I ask the question, I will let you know that I would have included some screenshots of my blocks-editor code, but my boss told me I had to keep the app 100% closed source, so I can't provide any. Hopefully I'm not being too vague.

Anyways, I set a FusionTablesControl query using the "make text" block and the Google API UPDATE query, but when I send the query on my test device (Samsung Galaxy Player 5), the overlaying "Fusion Tables" load screen pops up for only a split second (it normally shows for 2 or 3 seconds). When I check the tables, there has been no change.

I think syntax is still a potential problem because when I typed the encoded URL into google chrome's address bar, it still didn't update the table. Here is the basic syntax of what I typed into the address bar.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=UPDATE%20tableID%20SET%20(Column1%3Ddata1%2C%20Column2%3Ddata2%2C%20Column3%3Ddata3%2C%20Column4%3Ddata4)%20WHERE%20ROWID%20%3D%20%27rowID%27
```

The decoded URL after the "sql=" part is:

```
UPDATE tableID SET (Column1=data1, Column2=data2, Column3=data3, Column4=data4) WHERE ROWID = 'rowID'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, is it possible to set Google's API response to CSV instead of JSON?

Thanks,
~T16626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work like that, because you did not use authentication. More about that [see here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#auth):

> Identifying your application and authorizing requests
>
> Every request your application sends to the Fusion Tables API needs to
>   identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify
>   your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the
>   request) and/or using the application's API key. Here's how to
>   determine which of those options to use:
>
> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an
>   individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth
>   2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to. If the request doesn't require
>   authorization (such as a request for public data), then the
>   application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or
>   both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

**To access a fusion table with App Inventor**, you have 2 possibilities:

1. use the built-in fusiontable control blocks, how to set up everything for App Inventor please see the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/pizzaparty.html)
2. use the web component with authentication, [for details see here](http://puravidaapps.com/taifunFT2.php)

Comment: Do you know where I could find some help integrating the OAuth 2.0 into my app? From what you have provided, it does require OAuth Tokens.